# Invalid signed request. (Invalid signature.) when running two apps on IIS

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have tried absolutely everything...here is my scenario.

I have five apps running on IIS server, each in it's own folder with the proper web.config, containing FacebookSettings with AppID, Secret, etc.

Each app uses the same Authorize logic

```
 var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me", "email" } };

            if (auth.Authorize())
            {

                if (mode == "run")
                {
                    ShowWelcomeContent();
                }
                else if (mode == "runadmin")
                {
                    ShowEditContent();
                }

            }
```

It all works great when I hit the first app from Facebook.

Once I tried hitting the second app, it ALWAYS throws the same "Invalid signed request" error. If I change something and retry and access them in a separate order, the first app (whichever it is) always works, second to fifth always fail.

Answer (score 0):

That is cause it internally verifies the signed_request using the AppSecret for extra security.
So make sure you app seceret is set correctly for both the applications.

You might want to refer to this post on how to use it for multiple applications. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4931240/multiple-facebook-apps-under-one-web-application/4936703#4936703